# Rails request.referer didnt redirect to the previous url

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to redirect the canceled page to the previous one when the item's been canceled but at the moment the codes below don't work - can you help?

```
def destroy
  order.cancel

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to request.referer.include? "cancel" ? request.referer : order_path(order.shopify_id), notice: 'Order cancelled successfully!' }
  end
end

def cancel
  shopify_order.cancel

  fulfilment_orders.each do |fo|
    fo.update!(state: :cancelled) unless fo.state.in?(%i[shipped delivered could_not_deliver])
  end
end
```

Comment: why would you redirect to `request.referer` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully check the operator precedence as well as warnings you get while Ruby is executing your code.

Consider this snippet.

```
"cancel_foo_bar".include? "cancel" ? "foo" : "bar"
(pry):1: warning: string literal in condition
#⇒ true
```

It returns `true` because it’s actually equivalent to:

```
"cancel_foo_bar".include?("cancel" ? "foo" : "bar")
```

The same in your condition, `include?` receives the result of ternary operator execution, not `"cancel"` string. This probably would work:

```
format.html do
  redirect_url =
    if request.referer.include?("cancel")
      request.referer
    else
      order_path(order.shopify_id)
    end
  redirect_to(redirect_url,
    notice: 'Order cancelled successfully!')
end
```